# Creating a turtle that draws circles

Tags: python

I need to write a program that draws a pattern of circles that go move towards the top of the window and get smaller. Like, The pattern starts with the largest circle and then decreases the radius by a shrink value until the radius becomes very small (like 5 px).

My requirements for the minimum are complete, but to completely finish it I need to request X and Y positions, and request the radius and shrink value. Anyone know anything about this?

Might as well add, this is my second version of the code. The first version went up. It needs to go up. This one goes down. I have no idea what is wrong with it.

```
import turtle

turtle.penup()

for i in range(1, 500, 10):
    turtle.right(90)        # Face South
    turtle.forward(2 * i)   # Move two radiuses down
    turtle.right(270)       # Back to start heading
    turtle.pendown()        # Put the pen back down
    turtle.circle(i)        # Draw a circle
    turtle.penup()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your turtle is going the wrong way because you are using `turtle.forward`. Use `turtle.backward` instead.

Also, instead of doing `for x in range(1, 500, 10)`, use `for x in reversed(range(1, 500, 10))`, so that the radius decreases instead of increasing.

Lastly, for "requesting" the values, do you mean printing them out? If so, the radius is `i`, the shrink value is the third value of `range(start, stop, step)` and the X and Y values can be found with `turtle.position()`, which returns a Vector2D (essentially a tuple) of `(X, Y)`

Here's a modified version of your code:

```py
import turtle

turtle.penup()
turtle.sety(-400)

for i in reversed(range(1, 90, 10)):
    print("Radius: {radius}".format(radius=i))
    print("X: {0}, Y: {1}".format(*turtle.position()))
    print("Shrink value: 10")
    turtle.pendown()        # Put the pen back down
    turtle.circle(i)        # Draw a circle
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.right(90)        # Face South
    turtle.backward(2 * i)   # Move two radiuses down
    turtle.right(270)       # Back to start heading
```